# nginx ingress controller ssl passthrough not working with --enable-ssl-passthrough flag and annotation

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress

I am running a controller in ssl passthrough mode passing the argument --enable-ssl-passthrough
Also annotating ingress using nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: true

Controller args:

```
      containers:
      - args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-ingress-default-backend
        - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-ingress-controller
        - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
        - --controller-class=k8s.io/ingress-nginx
        - --ingress-class=nginx
        - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-ingress-controller
        - --enable-ssl-passthrough
```

Please note, I'm not passing any certificate here e.g.  - --default-ssl-certificate=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-tls-secret

This is my ingress resource

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
  name: ingress1
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: service-for-ingress-instance1
            port:
              number: 443
        path: /myservice/instance1
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

My expectation is," the controller to send TLS connections directly to the backend instead of letting NGINX decrypt the communication" as per document.

But in this case it is not sending traffic to the corresponding backend. with pathType: Prefix also doesn't work.

The moment I pass a certificate in controller args - --default-ssl-certificate=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-tls-secret it works and sends traffic to backend as expected.

**My questions:**

**1. Is it mandatory to pass certificate to the controller when I use the above ingress resource (path based routing)?
2. Does ssl-passthrough not work with path based routing ?**

But in this case it is not sending traffic to the corresponding backend. with pathType: Prefix also doesn't work.

What you expected to happen:

Without cert the path based routing should be working

NGINX Ingress controller version (exec into the pod and run nginx-ingress-controller --version.): 1.1.2

Kubernetes version (use kubectl version): 1.23.4

Without cert the path based routing should be working